# Algebraic solution to $2x + \ln x=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The answer to $2x+\ln x=2$ is $x=1$, which can be easily guessed after a failed attempt at solving it. I've tried to manipulate this into some inverse function of $2x+\ln x$, more specifically if $f(x)=2x+\ln x$, then I've tried to find $f^{-1}(x)$. But all I've gotten to is $xe^{2x}=e^2$, and I'm not sure how to simplify further.

Is there an algebraic solution to this? It seems like the product logarithm might be used, but I've only seen that function from Wolfram Alpha, and I'm not entirely sure how to use it.

Comment: take cases x>1 x<1 x=1

Comment: If you multiply by $2$ on both sides to get to $2x \cdot e^{2x} = 2 \cdot e^2$, the answer might be clearer.

Comment: Just because an equation is easy to write doesn't mean it is easy to solve.  In general, when you mix exponentials and polynomials, or logarithms, or functions of different types in general and then ask to solve the equation... you will very quickly enter the realm of "*non-elementary functions.*"  It is possible that you can get lucky and find a solution by inspection.  It might even be easy to prove that there must exist a solution.  Actually analytically finding the solution without inspection however can be very difficult if not outright impossible.

Comment: You might be lucky enough to have specifically named non-elementary functions such as the Lambert-W function.  In other cases however writing the solution is no better than just calling the solution "*the solution.*"  At that point, your only option might be to approximate the solution using numerical methods.  Even just altering your question to $2x+\ln(x)=3$ instead, you won't be able to write the value of $x$ any cleaner than "*the solution to $2x+\ln(x)=3$ near $1.349961838\dots$*" without using non-elementary functions like Lambert-W

Comment: Take the "simple" example $x = e^{-x}$. How would you find a solution in closed form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reiterating comments and complaints.

The way I read your question, you are asking for some function or method to algebraically/analytically solve the equation.  If we were told for instance that $x^2=4$ and were asked to find the positive value of $x$ satisfying this, sure we could say "*Oh, $2$ is the answer because look here... $2^2$ does in fact equal $4$*" but if we were to be asked about a similar question such as $x^2=3$ we would be hard-pressed to say "*Oh, $1.732050807568877\dots$ is the answer because $(1.732050807568877\dots)^2=3$.*"

For the question of solving $x^2=3$ for $x$, we were able to introduce a notation and concept... the square root... which allows us to answer this easily.  $x^2=3\implies x=\sqrt{3}$.  The way I read your question, you are looking for the analogous "operation" which lets us extract the value of $x$ from the above equation which uses this operation rather than just spotting the solution.  Spotting the solution for a particular case and proving it is indeed the solution is all well and good however it does nothing to help us find a solution in a similar problem with slightly changed values.

The answer to whether or not there is such an operation to solve for $x$ is that hoping for such an operation which solves a transcendental equation such as this is futile.  Any such operation will only be as useful as saying the solution is "*the solution*" and will be non-elementary.  In some related problems you will not have any conveniently named function to use.  In other problems you may have a function such as the [Lambert-W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) (*a.k.a. the product-log function as you alluded to in your post*) but actually using the Lambert-W in practice will generally require numerical methods to evaluate.

For this specific problem, looking at the generalized equation of $2x+\ln(x)=a$ you can indeed use the Lambert-W function.  Modifying the equation a bit, we have $e^{2x+\ln(x)}=e^a$ and $xe^{2x}=e^a$ and so $(2x)e^{(2x)}=2e^a$

This is of the form $we^w=z$ whose solution is $w=W_k(z)$ for some integer $k$ where $W_k$ is the Lambert-W function on the $k$'th branch.  That is, replacing the values of $w$ and $z$ for what we had $2x = W_k(2e^a)$ giving us

$$2x+\ln(x)=a\iff x = \frac{W_k(2e^a)}{2}$$

In the specific case of $a=2$ this does simplify to $W_k(2e^2)/2$ which simplifies to $1$, again using that $we^w=z\iff w=W_k(z)$

In the specific case of $a=3$ (*so the equation $2x+\ln(x)=3$*) this would not simplify well and would just be written as $W_k(2e^3)/2$ which one can find via numerical methods is approximately $1.3499618380\dots$

Answer (score 0):

$f$ increases, which says that our equation has one real root maximum.

But $1$ is a root, which says that we got the answer.

Comment: The fact that $1$ is the answer is besides the point.  The question is how to find $1$ analytically without trial and error, intuition, or inspection.

Comment: @JMoravitz  What to you mean? Is there mistake in my solution? I wait your reaction.

Comment: There is a mistake in your understanding of what is being asked.  Consider if the question were instead to solve for $x$ in $2x+\ln(x) = a$.  Yes, in the case that $a=2$ we have a fortuitous happenstance that $x=1$ works... which can be spotted by inspection and/or trial and error, etc... however the point is that it is unclear how to proceed (*if it is even possible to proceed*) in the case that a solution is *not* so easily spotted from the onset, for example in the case that $a=3$.

Comment: @JMoravitz  Read please, what is it an equation and what is it to solve an equation. I can give a link if you want. Now, think please, what do you say.

Comment: Right back at you.  Please learn what it means to "*read between the lines*" and understand the reason why the OP asked this question.  Simply verifying that $1$ is the answer to this specific instance is hardly useful.  Learning a technique to have found the corresponding solution(s) without inspection which can be applied to similar questions with slightly changed values is.

Comment: @JMoravitz The theory, which you tell us, has no any relation with math. Sorry, but it's which I see. Bye.

Comment: @JMoravitz I understand your point entirely, but let's not dismiss Rozenberg's logic on how there can only be one solution, too. Even though that partially answers the problem, and in fact the focus is, as you stated, more on how to systematically derive the solution, out of all the answers here, Rozenberg's is the most elegant. In theory it might sound great to employ more rigorous techniques to find the solution - in practice, if the question has such a trivial solution on inspection it doesn't provoke a strong need to tackle it as so. Problem is we *are* answering in benefit of the OP so...

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=2x-2-\ln x \implies f'(x)=2-\frac{1}{x}, f''(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}>0$$.
$f_{min}=f(1/2)=\ln 2-1<0$ and $f(0)=\infty, f(\infty)=\infty$, hence $f(x)=0$ has even number of roots. The only min at $x=1/2$ implies $f_{min}<0$, so there are only two real roots.

Further $f(0)=+\infty, f(1/2)<0$ implies one root on $(0,1/2)$ and $F(1)=0$ confirms the other root at $x=1$. Only graphical or numerical method can give the root in $(0,1/2)$.

Answer (score -1):

As noticed in the comments, in general we can't find elementary algebraic solutions to this kind of equations.

To proceed by elementary inequalities, in this special case we have that

$$2x + \ln x=2\iff \ln (x)=2(1-x)$$

and since

- for $x<1 \quad \ln (x)<0 \,\land\, 2(1-x)>0$
- for $x>1 \quad \ln (x)>0 \,\land\, 2(1-x)<0$
- for $x=1 \quad \ln (x)=2(1-x)=0$

$x=1$ is the unique solution for the given equation.

Comment: How does this help us solve a related question such as $2x+\ln(x)=3$ and in general $2x+\ln(x)=a$?

Comment: @JMoravitz I've reformulated the answer. I think that a solution by elementary inequalities could be fine in a precalculus context.

Comment: I reiterate the question in the previous comment.  How does this help us solve $2x+\ln(x)=3$?  Sure... we can do similarly and talk about what happens when $x<1.349961838$ and talk about what happens when $x>1.349961839$ and show that a solution must exist between those... but what is $1.349961838\dots$ equal to specifically and how to find/write it?  The ease of finding the breakpoint of $1$ by inspection in the original question should not be misconstrued as implying ease of finding the breakpoint in the $2x+\ln(x)=3$ problem.

Comment: @JMoravitz The solution here is referring to the specal case $2x + \ln x=2$ and we can prove with elementary arguments that $x=1$ is the unique solution. Of course I agree with you that in general we can't apply the method to find a particular solution but only to prove that it exists. However here, in this particular case, the solution seems fine to me also in a precalculus context.

Comment: @JMoravitz Which approach should you suggest instead? It would be useful to have a full answer also from you. Thanks

Comment: posted full answer above